# Reading data in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm not sure if I'm missing something I'm still new at Python, but I am reading a lot of Matlab files in a folder. In each matlab file, there are multiple arrays and I can do things with each array like plot and find the average, max min etc. My code works perfectly and reads the data correctly. Now, I want to add a while loop so it can keep running until I tell it to stop, meaning queuing the user to keep choosing folders that need the data to be read. However, when I run it the second time, it gives me this error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel like what the code is doing is adding the next set of data, to the overall data of the program. Which is why it gives me an error when at this line `maxGF=max(GainF)`. Because then it becomes an array of arrays...and it can't take the maximum of that.

when I load data from each matlabfile, this is how I did it:

```
Files=[] #list of files

for s in os.listdir(filename):
    Files.append(scipy.io.loadmat(filename+s))

for filenumber in range(0,length):

    #Gets information from MATLAB file and inserts it into array
    results[filenumber]=Files[filenumber]['results']   

    #Paramaters within MATLAB
    Gain_loading[filenumber]=results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['Gain'][0,0] #gets length of data within data array
    length_of_data_array=len(Gain_loading[filenumber])
    Gain[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['Gain'][0,0],length_of_data_array) #reshapes for graphing purposes
    PL_f0_dBm[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['PL_f0_dBm'][0,0],length_of_data_array)
    Pavs_dBm[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['Pavs_dBm'][0,0],length_of_data_array)
    PL_f0[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['PL_f0'][0,0],length_of_data_array)
    PL_2f0_dBm[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['PL_2f0_dBm'][0,0],length_of_data_array)
    CarrierFrequency[filenumber]=np.reshape(results[filenumber]['MeasurementParameters'][0,0]['CarrierFrequency'][0,0],length_of_data_array)
    Gamma_In[filenumber]=np.reshape(abs(results[filenumber]['PowerDomain'][0,0]['Gin_f0'][0,0]),length_of_data_array)
    Delta[filenumber]=PL_2f0_dBm[filenumber]-PL_f0_dBm[filenumber]
```

When I start doing stuff with the data like below, it works and it displays the correct data up until I run the max(GainF) command.

```
    GainF=[None]*length
    MaxPL_Gain=[None]*length

    #finds highest value of PL @ each frequency
    for c in range(0,length):
        MaxPL_Gain[c]=max(PL_f0_dBm[c])

MaxPL_Gain[:]=[x-6 for x in MaxPL_Gain] #subtracts 6dB from highest PL Values @ each frequency

for c in range (0,length):
   GainF[c]=np.interp(MaxPL_Gain[c],PL_f0_dBm[c],Gain[c]) #interpolates PL vs Gain. Finds value of Gain at 6dB backoff form max PL


maxGF=max(GainF)
```

I read other threads that said to use the seek(0) function. And I tried that with Files.seek(0) since that is where all my of data is initially saved, but when I run it it gives me the same error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'`

How do I reset all of my data? Help

UPDATE:
I tried the following code

```
for name in dir():
       if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]
```

And it works the way I want it to...or so I think. When I look at the PDF outputed from the program, I get distorted plots. It looks like the axis from the last program is still in the pdfs. Not just that, but when I run it 4-5 times, the spacing gets bigger and bigger and the graphs are further away from each other. How can I fix this error?

[distorted graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jlFo.png)

Comment: `Files` is a list of files, so you need to loop over each file (i.e. `for f in Files`) and in that single-file context, call `f.seek(0)`

Comment: Engineering code...makes me shiver...

Comment: @JacobIRR I do that, and it gives me this error:   'f.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'seek''

Comment: Could it be that you happen to hide the `max` function by defining a list called `max`? That could easily happen and would give the error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` as you saw initially.

Comment: @JohanL I doubled checked my code and that doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks though